# Public class must be defined in its own file

Tags: android, class

I am trying to use two views in one application to come up with the user's planetary weight. After rewriting the java several times, I finally have it working... mostly, but on the public class Planets it tells me "The public type planets must be defined in its own file." I went into the manifest and made an activity for it, but that didn't help anything. Planets is already the name of one of my xml files. How do I make the public type into its own file?

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/askwtTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="@string/askwt" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputwtEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/askwtTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/askwtTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/enterButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inputwtEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputwtEditText"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:onClick="buttonclick"
    android:text="@string/enter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Planets.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/planetTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/planet" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewform2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/mercuryRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/mercury" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/venusRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/venus" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/earthRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/earth" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/marsRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/mars" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/jupiterRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/jupiter" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/saturnRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/saturn" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/uranusRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/uranus" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/neptuneRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/neptune" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/plutoRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pluto" />
</RadioGroup>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/selectButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttonclick2"
    android:text="@string/select" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewform2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

</LinearLayout
```

JAVA:

```
package com.deitel.planetaryweight;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/* You should get used to declaring everything with the correct visibility.  Good  practice is to make everything private and use public mutator methods */
//Global variable
private double weight;
private Button enter;  // creates a button 

// Views
private EditText wtEntry;
private TextView txtForm2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Start with first screen
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterButton);

    //creates an editext and assigns the resource id of the xml edittext.
    wtEntry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputwtEditText);
    txtForm2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewform2);
}
// Button clicks shouldn't do anything but perform clicky actions. Leave field initialization, view creation, etc to the Activity.
//buttonclick for form 1
public void buttonclick(View view){
    //Receives the input from the edittext, converts it to a double (number).
    weight = Double.parseDouble(wtEntry.getText().toString());

    TextView t2 = null;
//change the value of the textview on screen 2 to the calculation value
   t2.setText(Double.toString(weight));

   // If you want a new layout, it's best to start a new activity.
   // It looks like you want to get information back, so use startActivityForResult().
   // setContentView(R.layout.planets);
   Intent dataIntent = new Intent(this, Planets.class);
   dataIntent.putExtra("com.deitel.identifier.DATA_WEIGHT", weight);
   startActivityForResult(dataIntent, Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Check that the resultCode is the same as we started the activity with
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        // get the double from the Intent, using the same string name (package  prefixed)
        // or a default value if it didn't get set.
        double resultWeight =  data.getDoubleExtra("com.deitel.identifier.RESULT_WEIGHT", 0.0);

        // Now do something with resultWeight
    }
}
}
// PlanetChooser.class
public class Planets extends Activity {
// constants, usually denoted by uppercase and declared static and final
public static final double MERCURYFORCE = 0.38; 
public static final double VENUSFORCE = 0.91; 
public static final double EARTHFORCE = 1.00; 
public static final double MARSFORCE = 0.38; 
public static final double JUPITERFORCE = 2.34; 
public static final double SATURNFORCE = 1.06; 
public static final double URANUSFORCE = 0.92;
public static final double NEPTUNEFORCE = 1.19;
public static final double PLUTOFORCE = 0.06;

private RadioButton mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune, pluto;

// No need to use the Double object as opposed to the primitive unless you have good reason
private double mercurypf, venuspf, earthpf, marspf, jupiterpf, saturnpf, uranuspf,  neptunepf, plutopf, weight;

// One variable will suffice, it seems.
private double resultForce;

public void onCreate(Bundle s){
    super.onCreate(s);
    setContentView(R.layout.planets);

    mercury = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.mercuryRadio);
    venus = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.venusRadio);
    earth = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.earthRadio);            
    mars = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.marsRadio);
    jupiter = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.jupiterRadio);
    saturn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.saturnRadio);
    uranus = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.uranusRadio);
    neptune = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.neptuneRadio);
    pluto = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.plutoRadio);
}
public void buttonclick2(View view){
    /*
    It looks to me here you're looking to see which box is checked, and set a value  based on 
    that planet.  Since instance variables (in this case mercurypf, jupiterpf, etc) are  initialized
    to the default value (0), there's no need to set them manually.
    */

    // Code used to determine which planet RadioButton is checked:
    if(mercury.isChecked())    {
        resultForce = MERCURYFORCE * weight;
    }
    if(venus.isChecked()){
        resultForce = VENUSFORCE * weight;
    }
    if(earth.isChecked()){
        resultForce = EARTHFORCE * weight;
    }
    if(mars.isChecked()){
        resultForce = MARSFORCE * weight;
    }
    if(jupiter.isChecked()){
        resultForce =JUPITERFORCE * weight;
    }
    if(saturn.isChecked()){
        resultForce = SATURNFORCE * weight;
    }
    if(uranus.isChecked()){
        resultForce = URANUSFORCE * weight;
    }
    if(neptune.isChecked()){
        resultForce = NEPTUNEFORCE * weight;
    }
    if(pluto.isChecked()){
        resultForce = PLUTOFORCE * weight;
    }
    // Create a new data Intent to pass back to the calling activity, set the result  code, 
    // and manually finish() this activity.
    Intent dataIntent = new Intent(this, null);
    dataIntent.getDoubleExtra("com.deitel.identifier.RESULT_DATA", resultForce);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, dataIntent);
    finish();
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.deitel.planetaryweight"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Planets" android:label="@string/title_planets"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 8):

Your Java file is named MainActivity.java (the name of the public class it defines). Remove the Planets class from it, and put that class into a Planets.java file. That's pretty much just how Java wants it to be.

Comment: IS it possible to keep just one java file?

Comment: No. Java won't let you do that (define multiple public classes in the same file). It's intrinsic to the language.

Comment: @John Sorry to bring up this old answer, but if you add that java code to a new java file, do you have to link to that file some how? Thanks

Comment: @pattyd: Short answer is "yes". For a usable answer, you'll likely want to open a new question and add some details about what you've got and what you're trying to accomplish.