# "The public type <<classname>> must be defined in its own file" error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have written the following code:

```
package staticshow;


public class StaticDemo {
  static int a = 3;
  static int b = 4;

  static {
    System.out.println("Voila! Static block put into action");
  }

  static void show() {
    System.out.println("a= " + a);
    System.out.println("b= " + b);
  }
}

public class StaticDemoShow {
  public static void main() {
    StaticDemo.show(); 
  }
}
```

I am getting the error message:

```
The public type StaticDemo must be defined in its own file
```

error in the very first line `public class StaticDemo {`. Why is it happening and how can I resolve it? Note that my project name is `StaticDemoShow`, package name is `staticshow` and class names are as given in the code.

**EDIT**- After making just one class public or both the classes default, I am getting the error "Selection does not contain a main type". Now what should I do?

Comment: Is your class file named StaticDemo?

Comment: @VaughanHilts, No. My project name is "StaticDemoShow".

Comment: No need to downvote IMHO. Every beginner will stumble across this. @VaughanHilts It seems both are in the same file.

Comment: duplicate of [Java compiler error: "public type .. must be defined in its own file"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084005/java-compiler-error-public-type-must-be-defined-in-its-own-file) and [Public class must be defined in its own file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405691/public-class-must-be-defined-in-its-own-file) and a lot more I guess…

Comment: just **in case** you need to **rightfully have mulitple types in one file**, you may get here and look for another answer and motivation provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012525/the-public-type-classname-must-be-defined-in-its-own-file-bad-style-or-nice/32012526#32012526

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If `.java` file contains top level (not nested) `public` class, it has to have the same name as that public class. So if you have class like `public class A{...}` it needs to be placed in `A.java` file. Because of that **we can't have two public classes in one `.java` file**.

If having two public classes would be allowed then, and lets say aside from public `A` class file would also contain `public class B{}` it would require from `A.java` file to be *also* named as `B.java` but files can't have two (or more) names (at least in all systems on which Java can be run).

So assuming your code is placed in `StaticDemoShow.java` file you have two options:

1. If you want to have other class in same file make them non-public (lack of visibility modifier will represent *default/package-private* visibility)

   ```
    class StaticDemo { // It can no longer public

        static int a = 3;
        static int b = 4;

        static {
            System.out.println("Voila! Static block put into action");
        }

        static void show() {
            System.out.println("a= " + a);
            System.out.println("b= " + b);
        }

    }

    public class StaticDemoShow { // Only one top level public class in same .java file
        public static void main() {
            StaticDemo.show();
        }
    }
   ```
2. Move all public classes to their own `.java` files. So in your case you would need to split it into two files:

   - StaticDemo.java

     ```
       public class StaticDemo { // Note: same name as name of file

           static int a = 3;
           static int b = 4;

           static {
               System.out.println("Voila! Static block put into action");
           }

           static void show() {
               System.out.println("a= " + a);
               System.out.println("b= " + b);
           }

       }
     ```
   - StaticDemoShow.java

     ```
       public class StaticDemoShow { 
           public static void main() {
               StaticDemo.show();
           }
       }
     ```

Comment: Coming from C#, this limitation is very irritating

Comment: Any insight as to why?

Answer (score 18):

Cant have two public classes in same file

```
   public class StaticDemo{
```

Change to

```
   class StaticDemo{
```

Comment: I recommend you add private in in StaticDemoShow to make it more clear.

Comment: getting error "Selection does not contain a main type"

Comment: @Mistu4u make the StaticDemoShow as parent class  and other as nested class. follow the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: @Mitsu4U Switch it the other way around making the other class non public and the one with your `main` public. See edit.

Answer (score 12):

Java rule : One `public` class in one file.

Answer (score 2):

Save this class in the file **StaticDemo.java**.
Also you cant have more than one public classes in one file.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use 2 public class instances, you need to use one. Try using class (name) instead of public class (name)

Answer (score 2):

> error in the very first line public class StaticDemo {

Any Class `A` which has access modifier as `public` must have a separate source file as `A.java` or `A.jav`. [**This is specified in JLS 7.6 section**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6):

> If and only if packages are stored in a file system (§7.2), the host
>   system may choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time
>   error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the
>   type name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav) if either of the
>   following is true:
>
> - The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the package in which the type is declared.
> - The type is declared **public** (and therefore is potentially accessible from code in other packages).

However, you may have to remove `public` access modifier from the Class declaration `StaticDemo`. Then as `StaticDemo` class will have no modifier it will become *package-private*, That is, it will be visible only within its own package.

Check out [**Controlling Access to Members of a Class**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one public class in a file else you will get the error what you are getting now and name of file must be the name of public class

Answer (score 0):

I had two significant errors in my program. From the other answers, I learned in a single java program, one can not declare two classes as "public". So I changed the access specifier, but got another error as added to my question as "EDIT" that "Selection does not contain a main type". Finally I observed I forgot to add "String args[]" part in my main method. That's why the code was not working. After rectification, it worked as expected.