# The public type <<classname>> must be defined in its own file: bad style or nice feature

Tags: java

*(Since I got this error in a special situation where it actually makes sense to me.
I would like to share some insights and workarounds not mentioned elsewhere for similar questions here...)*

```
/* e.g. located in a src/main/java/mypkg/MyKeys.java file */
package mypkg;

public enum EditStatus { ... }
public enum CustomerTypeKey { ... }  // the suggestion of an IDE could be
                                     // to move this one to its own file
// ...
```

Now I want to have those types packed in one file as explained in my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **simple answer**: **if its not a big deal to move those types to separate files each, then one should do it!**

**although** its **generally bad practice!** (as shown e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814713/the-public-type-classname-must-be-defined-in-its-own-file-error-in-eclipse)) to put multiple types into one "java container" file (and you may get there via Google like me :-) ), there are (rare) **situations where this makes sense**, e.g.

2. stuff rightfully contained in a **[package-info.java](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/whats-package-info-java-for/)** (like annotation types etc.) or
3. if you e.g. re-generate a lot of (likely similar in nature) types and for simplicity want to keep it in one file, e.g. if you create/keep-in-sync enums from database "keys" (like I have to).

   - Then you can just **wrap** those types **by some "parent class"**, e.g.

     ```
         /** do not edit! auto-generated if DB schema changes */
         class MyKeys { 
           public enum EditStatusKey { ... }
           public enum CustomerTypeKey { ... } 
           ... // maybe many(!) other types following
         }
     ```

     and access them via `MyKeys.EditStatusKey...`

     - keep in mind to maybe use `static` inner classes (e.g. `public static class EditStatusKeys { ... }` if you are not using Enums (like in my case)

*(just in case you doubt my example: the automation around my db-java-code sync logic would be unnecessary complicated to work on multiple files (there are more than 30 types auto-generated from a single table) and the benefit in the Java environment is not there and it may even be worse using it)*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure and check that the class name is the same as the .java file name, that is the reason that I got the error above.