# Keep getting 404 with JAX-RS, jersey and tomcat 8, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

Just posting all the classes, I've tried a ton of different setups from different tutorials / guides etc. But they all result in a 404. The tomcat 8 server is a clean install.

This is my first time working with jax-rs and jersey, I have a lot of experience with java and some with tomcat 8.

I wanted to try to implement a rest-service api and seperating back-end from front-end, and it seemed as though jax-rs and jersey was the best solution for implementing this in java(?).

The address I am trying is: localhost:8080/EventCalendar/rest/hello

which yields:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /EventCalendar/rest/hello

type Status report

message /EventCalendar/rest/hello

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>EventCalendar</groupId>
  <artifactId>EventCalendar</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Servlet 3.0 API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JAX-RS RESTful Web Services -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

</web-app>
```

RestConfig

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RESTConfig extends Application {

    public RESTConfig() {
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> returnValue = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        returnValue.add(TestService.class);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

TestService

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class TestService
{

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String info(){
        return "This is the testservice";
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the url be localhost:8000/rest/hello? Regarding your question about java and jersey for rest api - you could also try looking into spring-boot, very easy to use, very well documented, and have an embedded tomcat running with it (so you get a .jar file. It is also possible to separate into a .war if you wanted).

Comment: No because the project name is EventCalendar, it adds a level to the url.
Do you have any good tutorials to read up on it? I'll take a look :)!

Comment: http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ simple hello-world example like your own. Their documentation and own tutorials are pretty good tbh.

Comment: On another note, i'm pretty sure that `@ApplicationPath` specifies the base-url for the servlet, and does not take the project name into account. Have you tried without "EventCalendar" in the URI?

Comment: I did try the url you specified, but it still gave me the same result :/

Comment: If you don't change the final name for the build, then it will be `${artifactId}-${version}`. So instead of the context path being `EventCalendar`, it would be `EventCalendar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. Some IDEs will have the default context path be the project name, I am not sure if that is the case with you or not. If not, you can change the final name to be just the artifact id, by adding `<finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>` inside the `<build>` in your pom.

Comment: @peeskillet using eclipse, when I right click the project and tell it to run on server EventCalendar is the root url.  I had to run to a lecture, but I will try this later

Comment: I have not had time to check out peeskillets proposal,  but nothing else has worked so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the other given solutions helped me for some reason.
I ended up with not creating a maven project importing the newest jars and installing a plugin for eclipse that automatically creates the service and adds them to the web.xml.

But thanks for all the effort to help :)!

Plugin:
RESTful Plugin for Eclipse

Edit: Just wanted to add that this removes the possibility that it was my server setup that was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Set the path for the function StringInfo() inside test Service class...

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/TestService")
    public String info(){
        return "This is the testservice";
    }
```

Also you have not set the url in web.xml....

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>package-name</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Add all this...and then access the url...
 localhost:8080/EventCalendar/rest/hello/TestService

Comment: The variable for @Path has to be a string(?) so I understood it as you wanting me to set it as "TestService" ? This didn't yield a different result..

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

Comment: It is not finding the specified class as my comment above shows

Comment: The issue is with the web.xml..try adding the above given code to web.xml...updated it

Comment: Fails to startup due to:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name ServletAdaptor

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the servlet declaration in `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>your.package.RESTConfig</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>your.package.RESTConfig</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

See documentation of Jersey https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#deployment.servlet.3

Comment: "MultiException stack 1 of 1
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The public type RESTConfig must be defined in its own file"

Comment: Solution to this exception should be this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19814983/1885467

Answer (score 1):

The servlet must be declared in your `web.xml`:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.my.package.TestService</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>



<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Replace `com.my.package.TestService` with your fully qualified class name

Also make sure your .war is deployed as `EventCalendar`. The way your question is asked, you seem to miss that in the URL, the application name comes before the resource name. In the Tomcat manager, it should look like this:

[Tomcat manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMTkA.png)

If your application is not named `EventCalendar` but `myApp`, the URL would be `localhost:8080/myApp/rest/EventCalendar/hello`

Answer (score 1):

I seems your source code is fine and you comply with requested minimum. I believe the problem in tomcat configuration. For instance check if tomcat work at all and respond to its root url and pay attention to your project directory name in the tomcat webapps folder.